# WPF - data binding - no updates even with INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf

I am totally a new to the WPF application and start learning how to code the application.
During I tried to write a simple code to examine how it works, the code could not work as expected.

The intention is just to get the current system time by Datetime.Now and show it on Textblock updated every 500ms.  -  I just want test the environment that the code is running and processing behind the window to get/calculate the latest data and show it on the window.

However, with the simple code below, the text on the window just get the time once and never been updated while the loop is running and "ClockText" is being updated.

I am sure I made a stupid mistake, but I could not find where the wrong point is. Please give me your help!

[MainWindow.xaml]

```
<Window x:Class="wpfTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40"
               Text="{Binding ClockText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

</Grid>
```

[MainWindow.xaml.cs]

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Clock clk;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        clk = new Clock() { ClockText = "HH:MM:SS" };
        this.DataContext = clk;
        clk.ClockLogic(ref clk);
    }
}
public class ClockViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string clockText;
    public string ClockText
    {
        get { return clockText; }
        set
        {
            clockText = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ClockText");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));

    }
}

public class Clock
{
    public string ClockText { get; set; }
    public async void ClockLogic()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ClockText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(ClockText); // for debug
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `Clock` needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: You implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `ClockViewModel` but assign `Clock` to the `DataContext`. The `DataContext` has to have the interface implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you bind to the `ClockText` property of the `Clock` and not to the `ClockViewModel`, the `Clock` class needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `ClockText` property whenever you set it:

```
public class Clock : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    private string clockText;
    public string ClockText
    {
        get { return clockText; }
        set
        {
            clockText = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(ClockText));
        }
    }

    public async void ClockLogic()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ClockText = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(ClockText); // for debug
            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }

}
```

You don't seem to initialize and use your `ClockViewModel` class somewhere.

Comment: Consider using `CallerMemberNameAttribute` on the `info` parameter of `NotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear answer! The code now works. Now I am bit wondering what is the best way to implement the view model by code-behind as many websites explain to have Viewmodel class. Should I use Viewmodel class to initialize at Mainwindow class and bind to Datacontext?